# Foreach and while loop prints the same value

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to get the info from each user, this is what I am trying:

```
$db_conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "foo", "bar", "users");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Ocurrio un error en la conexion de la base de datos: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); exit();
}

// I got $evUsers from previous MySQL query
// It looks like: 1,2,4,6,10,25;
// Each number = userID
$cleanUsers = preg_replace('/\;$/', '', $evUsers);
$members = explode(',', $cleanUsers);

foreach($members as $member){
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conexion, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=$member");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $memberID = $row['userID'];
        $memberName = $row['userName'];
        $memberAddress = $row['userAddress'];

        echo "ID: ".$memberID." - Name: ".$memberName." - Address: ".$memberAddress.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($db_conexion);
```

This code prints the info from the first user over and over again.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need the `while` loop? Can there be more than one user with the same userID?

Comment: First off, you are only freeing the result of the last query, you should put the call to `mysql_free_result` inside the loop on members, at the end.

Comment: Why do you do a separate query for each userID? Why not `WHERE userID IN ($cleanUsers)`?

Comment: But this problem would be avoided if you did a single query for all the user ids (`WHERE userID IN ($cleanUsers)`).

Comment: I can't see any reason for it to get stuck on a single userID. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: I tried adding mysql_freeresult inside the loop, didn't work.

Comment: @Sebastian Check for a mysql error just before the while loop. Maybe there's no table `users` ;)

Comment: @hex494D49 It returns the first ID so exists, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
$members = preg_replace('/\;$/', '', $evUsers);
//$members = explode(',', $cleanUsers); <--- take this off

//foreach($members as $member){ <--- take this off as well
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID IN ($members)");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $memberID = $row['userID'];
        $memberName = $row['userName'];
        $memberAddress = $row['userAddress'];

        echo "ID: ".$memberID." - Name: ".$memberName." - Address: ".$memberAddress.PHP_EOL;
    }
//}
```